# Excel Row Headings Widths

Tags: excel, vba, settings, rows

How do you set the row heading width back to default setting?

I have trawled all around the internet for an answer to this question, so would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

I have a workbook with 10 worksheets, and all of the row headings are normal and fine, except for on one tab, where the width of the headings has increased to approximately the size it would be at the bottom of the page (on row 1048576).

When all of the rows are displayed, the row heading width is fine, however I only want to display the top 5 rows (the rest are currently meaningless to the tab), but when I hide the rows below row 5, the row heading width increases.

Image: Row Headings at increased width
[image: Image: Row Headings at increased width]

It appears like it is a setting which is automatically adjusting the width, but I cannot find the option in the ribbon or in the VBA object browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: So what is your actual question? You didn't ask one. Are you sure you mean width and not height? Your image shows the row height but you talk about width! Please [edit]/correct your question for clarification. The row height usually adjusts to the data in the row if *word wrap* is activated. But you can set the height whatever you like to or turn *word wrap* off.

Comment: Hi Peh, I have edited to ask my question, apologies. And yes as strange as it sounds I do actually mean the width. I want the row headings to go back to the normal width. All my worksheets are set up exactly the same in this workbook, however this is the only one which changes the width as described above.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean, I'm sorry I just saw the different height of the rows. Can you tell **how** exactly you hide the rows? Is there any VBA code you hide the rows with? Or is it manually? Because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I hide them manually. And I've also had problems reproducing the error which is making it harder to figure out the solution.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in a new worksheet by changing the row height of any row that will be hidden later e.g. row 1048575 and hiding e.g rows 5 up to last manually. But even deleting **all** rows (1 to 1048576) in a sheet it doesn't reset the row header width to narrow. Keeping the narrow width only works in a new worksheet: So I suggest to copy the data over into a new sheet and delete the old one.

Comment: @pnuts I tried saving, closing Excel completely and then re-open the file during my tests to reproduce/solve it without any success. It doesn't shrink back.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, once that wide headers occur they persist. Even deleting **all** rows within the sheet by selecting all and really remove/delete them (NOT just empty them) then saving, reopen and hide from row x to last: -> issue persists. Looks like a strange bug.

Comment: @pnuts no worries, it's always good to look at an issue twice or more. - but that's what I think too: It's not a behavior we would expect from Excel.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, that has solved the issue. It still seems like a strange occurrence in Excel though. It's as if they thought of the eventuality that it would need to expand, but not need to shrink.